# disabling smartd service for a web server

Tags: web-server, smart

I've read in a few places that the smartd service is not needed for running a web server, but no explanation is given for why this is so.

Why would it be a good idea to turn this service off when it could potentially be giving you timely warnings of imminent disk failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it's causing a problem, it's not a smart idea to turn it off. Checking things like smart data is always useful, and worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess if your server booted from an iSCSI drive and didn't have any local drives it would be pointless to run. But if you have any local drives that the server uses (which I'm sure you do) you should keep it on. It's not going to hog resources or bog the system down. Just remember, even if it's running you still need to watch the logs for the actual message!